# Passar variável PHP no AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho um arquivo script.js que precisa capturar uma variável em php, como faço?

**Veja o que tenho:**

```
function atualizaFotos() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "imovel-fotos-id.php?cliente=&cod="
    }).done(function (resposta) {
        $("#fotos").html(resposta);
    });

}
```

Tenho a variável cliente e a variável código. Como capturar uma variável php e passá-la neste parametro?

Aguardo ajuda!

Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar sua variável `php` num `input` tipo `hidden`, e enviar via parâmetros para o arquivo `js`.
Por exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cliente" value="<?php echo $var_cliente_php; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="codigo" value="<?php echo $var_codigo_php; ?>">
<input type="button" onclick="atualizaFotos(document.getElementById("cliente").value, document.getElementById("codigo").value)" value="Enviar">
```

e sua função jQuery ficaria assim:

```
function atualizaFotos(pCliente, pCodigo) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "imovel-fotos-id.php?cliente="+pCliente+"&cod="+pCodigo
  }).done(function (resposta) {
    $("#fotos").html(resposta);
  });
}
```

Comment: Aconselho proteger as variáveis `$var_cliente_php` e `$var_codigo_php` com `htmlentities` e/ou `json_encode` (tratar UTF-8 se necessário).